# Import openCV always shows error

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

I always face an import error when i want to open an Android Project from Existing Code. This error only happens if the project integrate with OpenCV.
Below are the screenshot :

[image: OpenCV import error]

I am new to Android programming and OpenCV. Pls help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

first download the SDK of http://opencv.org/downloads.html , after import the SDK to your project, in the page include the tutorial for import and samples.

I hope I've helped.